# How Can I import json data in Vue Js with axios

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My JSON Data is like  this which was earlier saved in js file of vue & was accessing it from there 
I want my html v-for: condition to work as it was working fine earlier
I tried the method in Docs of Vue js but it couldn't fetch the json data & execute it , plese help if anyone can.

```
variants: [
            {
                variantId:501,
                variantImage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
                variantname: 'alpha',
                typeslug: 'men',
                dialname: '26.5x28.5' ,


                items: [
                    {
                        itemId: 1,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
                        itemcolour: 'gold'
                    },
                     {
                        itemId: 2,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_4.png',
                        itemcolour: 'pink',
                    },
                    {
                        itemId:3,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
                        itemcolour: 'black'
                    },

                ]

            },
              {
                variantId:502,
                variantImage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
                variantname: 'alpha',
                  typeslug: 'women',
                   dialname: '35',
                    items: [
                    {
                        itemId: 1,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
                        itemcolour: 'gold'
                    },
                     {
                        itemId: 2,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_4.png',
                        itemcolour: 'pink',
                    },
                    {
                        itemId:3,
                        itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
                        itemcolour: 'black'
                    },

                ]
            } ],
```

My Vue code is like this

```
var watchslider = new Vue({

    el: '#Products',

   data() {
    return {
          Variants: []
    }
  },
     mounted() {
     axios
      .get('./products.json')
      .then(response => {
          this.Variants = response.data

                        }) 
           .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
    })
           } 

});
```

But I am Unable to fetch data from json & execute it  in my html

```
    <div id="Products" class="responsive py-5">

     <div v-for="(variant,variantIndex) in variants"  :key="variant.variantId" class="col-lg-4 col-4 p-5">

    <p>{{variant.variantImage}}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're storing the response data in `posts`, shouldn't it be `variants`?

Comment: @pai.not.pi    I updated the question , it's not  working with the  variants as well

Comment: I am Getting by json data like this @pai.not.pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of 3 reasons.

1) your json is invalid

try this

```
    {
    "variants": [
      {
        "variantId": 501,
        "variantImage": "assets/images/demo_watch_1.png",
        "variantname": "alpha",
        "typeslug": "men",
        "dialname": "26.5x28.5",
        "items": [
          {
            "itemId": 1,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_2.png",
            "itemcolour": "gold"
          },
          {
            "itemId": 2,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_4.png",
            "itemcolour": "pink"
          },
          {
            "itemId": 3,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_1.png",
            "itemcolour": "black"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "variantId": 502,
        "variantImage": "assets/images/demo_watch_2.png",
        "variantname": "alpha",
        "typeslug": "women",
        "dialname": "35",
        "items": [
          {
            "itemId": 1,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_2.png",
            "itemcolour": "gold"
          },
          {
            "itemId": 2,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_4.png",
            "itemcolour": "pink"
          },
          {
            "itemId": 3,
            "itemimage": "assets/images/demo_watch_1.png",
            "itemcolour": "black"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

2) You use different variable in HTML and javascript file , both should be same

```
 <div v-for="(variant,variantIndex) in Variants" :key="variant.variantId" class="col-lg-4 col-4 p-5">
            <p>{{variant.variantImage}}</p>
        </div>



new Vue({

    el: '#Products',

    data() {
        return {
            Variants: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('./products.json')
            .then(response => {
                this.Variants = response.data.variants

            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e)
            })
    }

});
```

3) you dont need to put vue instance in a variable `watchslider`

Comment: I changed the Variable to variable in my vue js & it executed the json data in {{variants}} but now it's running the loop based upon the data it has but I am unable to fetch details like :v-for variant in variants under this it's not executing anything like {{variant.variantname}}     @MA Rahman

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the delimiters `{{ }}` in your markup for your data binding.

You'll need to change this line,

`<p>{{ variant.variantImage }}</p>`

Comment: I was trying with delimiters  only , Forgot to add in stack question I updated it , but still couldn't work

Comment: What's the issue? do you get any errors? what's the current output?

Comment: In console It's  showing error     ReferenceError: variants is not defined                             at wn.eval (eval at Ya (vue.min.js:6), <anonymous>:3:88)
    at wn.e._render (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.r (vue.min.js:6)
    at fn.get (vue.min.js:6)
    at new fn (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at wn.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.t._init (vue.min.js:6)
    at new wn (vue.min.js:6)

Comment: There's a case mismatch. Some part of your code has `Variants` with a capital `V` and some other places it's `variants` with a lowercase `v`

Comment: I changed the Variable to   variable in my vue js  & it executed the  json  data in  {{variants}}   but now it's running the loop based upon the  data it has but I am unable to  fetch details like   :v-for variant in variants     under this it's not executing  anything like {{variant.variantname}}            @pai.not.pi    thankyou